# How does kube-proxy loadbalancing

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, kube-proxy

I understand that nodes in K8s cluster will all have `kube-proxy` running and any node can forward traffic for any service in the cluster.

Lets say I have a service with two replica pods which are running on two Nodes `N1` and `N2`. The external load balancer forwards traffic to `N3` and `N4`. The first request reaches `N3` and `N3`'s `kube-proxy` diverts the traffic to `N1`. The second request reaches `N4` and `N4`'s `kube-proxy` diverts the traffic to N2.

Do `kube-proxy`s communicate with each other so that `N4`'s `kube-proxy` is aware that earlier request was forwarded to `N1` and so it should divert this request to `N2` for proper load balancing or the decision is local to that `kube-proxy` and not coordinated across `kube-proxy` in which case it doesn't correctly load balance ?

Answer (score 0):

Each kube-proxy instance load balances separately.

Answer (score 0):

`Kube-Proxy` does not communicate with each other, they only talks to `apiserver` to get services and their endpoints information.

Load Balance is conducted separately on each `kube-proxy`. Since the default LB algorithm is random, there is no need to make things complicated.